# Programmatically changing filenames without breaking shortcuts

Tags: windows-vista, shortcuts, mp3, tags

I have a folder with several gigabytes of mashups. They are are all mp3s and named like this "title [remixer]". The artist tag is "artist1 vs. artist2 vs ..." and the title tag is exactly like the filename (plus the occasional '?', ':' or other character that can't be used in a filename.).

What I want to do is put the name of the remixer in the artist tag and the names of the original artists in the filename and title between the square brackets. Additionally there are shortcuts on my harddrive that point to these tracks. I would need to update the path of the shortcut because the filename of the track changed and also update the names of the shortcuts to the new filenames.

If I do all that by hand it would take me many hours. What's the best way to do this programmatically? I'm using Vista 64.

Comment: If push comes to shove and you have to do it manually, try to make listings of the texts and listings of the files. You can combine these in an editor to create batch files to do the job.

Comment: Your question becomes clearer if you add some before/after examples of filename/artist tag/title tag.

Answer (score 0):

The dealbreaker is the shortcuts. All the tagging and renaming can easily be done in the freeware [mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/index.html).

Correcting the shortcuts would require programming. Any language that allows file operations and has plugins for tagging would do. I would use [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) for that.

If you can't program it's probably easier to do recreate the shortcuts by hand.